# Laravel Blade Explode Html

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a loop that literates through my multi array but I need each entry to by styled using the blade syntax. I've tried echoing out the Html with php but that didn't work.

This is what I'm trying to do in a Blade syntax

```
 echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
```

Array

```
    array:2 [▼
  0 => {#173 ▼
    +"Name": "Rama Berger"
    +"StockName": "apple"
    +"price": 100
    +"Date": "2016-01-07 17:31:06"
  }
  1 => {#172 ▼
    +"Name": "Rama Berger"
    +"StockName": "apple"
    +"price": 11
    +"Date": "2016-01-07 20:00:38"
  }
]
```

View

```
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Stock</th>
                   <th>Order Amount</th>
                   <th>Date</th><br>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               @foreach($History as $Past)
                   @foreach($Past as $key)
                       <tr>
                           <td>{{$key}}</td>
                       </tr>
                   @endforeach
               @endforeach
           </tbody>
      </table>
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \View as View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

 class RequestController extends BaseController
{
    public function GetHistory(){
        $name = Auth::user()->name;
        $History =  DB::table('History')->select('Name', 'StockName', 'price', 'Date')->where('StockName', '=', 'apple')->get();
        return view('pages.home')->with('History', $History);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide valid code. Now, it's missing table tags

Comment: Please provide full code. Also display Error !!  And you have </table> in For-each loop but where <table> tag ? it should not be in Inside Loop ? Or you can write start and end tag in loop or outside loop. Follow the sequence

Comment: After you echoing $key, what is inside?

Comment: the $key contained a multi array but now passes independent elements of the the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible things for your question.

1) Check your blade file. It's should be like `filename.blade.php`

2) Your array have some problem. If your array is object array, you should print out like that `{{ $key->yourValue }}`. Otherwise, `{{ $key['yourValue'] }}`

If you provide your array sample, we can provide better answer for your question.

Hope this help! I want to suggest you one thing for coding standard.

According to `PSR` standard, you should follow `PSR` standard. I'm not recommend to declare like `$History`. It's should be like `$history`. You can reference from [here](http://www.php-fig.org)

Change to this

```
 @foreach($History as $Past)
      <tr>
          @foreach($Past as $key)
              <td>{{$key}}</td>
          @endforeach
      </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you and i did upload an array sample just now

Comment: @Charles Can you `var_dump` your array?

Comment: I found it to be working now thank you a lot but possibly if its not too much trouble you could help me with one more i cant seem to get my td to go vertical it only seems to want to go horizontal even after i have it set in a tr the html is the same i can post a img of the error specifily for a better visualization https://gyazo.com/c042a1241a01242ea4b07eac4c7d9b83